# Close all presentations in the background without the ActivePresentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

This one really annoys me! I try to close all presentations that might be opened in the background (visible or not) without the active one that executes the macro.

The Thing here is, that the For Each loop does not iterate through all files even though it schould do that:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim pres As PowerPoint.presentation
' Closes most of the presentations BUT NOT ALL of them
For Each pres In PowerPoint.Application.Presentations
    If pres.name <> PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.name Then
        pres.Close
        Set pres = Nothing
    End If
Next
```

After that **not all** presentations are closed. A few are still opened! I can see that `Close` gets called, but some presentations stay opened.

So - knowing this is not a nice solution - I tried to iterate again over all presentaions. This time using the `PowerPoint.Application.Presentations.Count` property. But all it does is running into a

```
For i = 1 To PowerPoint.Application.Presentations.Count
    Dim name As String
    Set pres = PowerPoint.Application.Presentations(i)
    If pres.name <> PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.name Then
        pres.Close
        Set pres = Nothing
    End If
Next
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here on this one.

---

**This** is **not** an option! :D

```
While PowerPoint.Application.Presentations.Count > 1
    For Each pres In PowerPoint.Application.Presentations
        If pres.name <> PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.name Then
            pres.Saved = 1
            pres.Close
            Set pres = Nothing
        End If
    Next
Wend
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to properly remove objects from a collection (which `Presentations` is), you need to go backwards. If not, the item gets removed from the collection, every item "behind" it gets shifted forward - but then you increase the counter and therefore skip one!

Therefore, try this:

```
For i = Presentations.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Presentations(i).Name <> _
        ActivePresentation.Name Then
        Presentations(i).Close
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, but could you explain why the `For Each` loop does not behave as I expected?

Comment: The `For Each` does not work properly, as internally it's doing nothing else then using a counter (at least I assume). Using `Next` will increase the counter - but due to the closing, the indexes of the remaining presentations have shifted to the left, so one is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CloseAllOtherPresentation()
 Dim ChooseButton As VbMsgBoxResult
 ChooseButton = MsgBox("WARNING!! All opened presentation will    close,Continue?", vbYesNo, "")
 If ChooseButton = vbYes Then
        Dim i As Integer
          For i = Presentations.Count To 1 Step -1
             If Presentations(i).Name <> ActivePresentation.Name Then
                Presentations(i).Save
                Presentations(i).Close
              End If
          Next
   End If
```

End Sub

---

When you delete an item from a collection, the index of the collections updates 
eg. A=1 , B=2, C=3, D=4 E=5 F=6 [A-F are objects,numbers are the index].
for iteration function, the counter increases let say CT represent counter.
WHEN FOR LOOP IS USED to remove Objects in a forward manner :)

CT=1, A is removed, arrangement now is

```
B=1, C=2, D=3 E=4 F=5
```

CT=2, C will be remove because is now the second item, hence we have

```
 B=1, D=2 E=3 F=4
```

CT=3 ?, and so on. At the end instead of deleting all it leaves

```
 B=1,D=2,F=3
```

Because of this, in removing objects from collection, we start from backward